# Can you enable -Werror=format in Clang, but still allow non-literal format strings? (without using -Wno-format-security)

Tags: c++, clang, suppress-warnings

I just added `-Werror=format` to our makefiles, and I started getting some errors where we were passing non-literal format strings to printf-like functions. (Yeah, not the best idea, but it was mostly in tests, and other places where it's not actually a problem, this would be a breaking change)

So I also added `-Wno-format-nonliteral`, but it doesn't seem to do anything: https://godbolt.org/z/1x6YvY4d5

Actually, it seems that this option is kinda broken in clang? No warnings/errors from the following when compiling w/ `-Wno-format-security -Wformat-nonliteral`:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void foo() {
    char buff[10];
    printf(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/a5Gnz537W

Comment: The compiler error message you linked ends with: `[-Werror,-Wformat-security]`. so, technically it can be disabled with `-Wno-format-security`

Comment: I guess I left off the implicit constraint that I wanted `-Wformat-security`'s _other_ checks...

Comment: I cannot find clang description for `format-security` but gcc documentation [says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html): _At present, this warns about calls to printf and scanf functions where the format string is not a string literal and there are no format arguments, as in printf (foo)_ So, `printf(nonLiteral, arg)` is `format-nonliteral` warning and `printf(nonLiteral)` cause `format-security` and there are currently no other cases it handles according to gcc docs. it seems it is just the same in clang.

Comment: Ah, then this looks like a misunderstanding on my part, I assumed that `-Wformat-security` was the part which checked for invalid format arguments (wrt the format string)

Comment: I am tempted to just write an answer "`Can you enable -Werror=format in Clang, but still allow non-literal format strings? (without using -Wno-format-security)` No.". Bottom line, I do not understand why not just `printf("%s", fgets(...)` or `fputs` it.